# How to use sscanf to find the lowercase letters in a string

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

I am trying to get this little snippet of code to add and print out all the lowercase letters in a char pointer. It prints out ab and says the count is two, but it does print anything else out? I want it to add a, b, d, and f to the array named temp. I have looked up quite a bit of info on the internet but no luck. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
main(){

char *str = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
char temp[200];
int count = 0;
if(str == NULL){
    printf("Error");
}

str[0] = 'a';
str[1] = 'b';
str[2] = 'C';
str[3] = 'd';
str[2] = 'E';
str[3] = 'f';
str[4] = '\0';
int res;
while(1){
    res = sscanf(str, "%[a-z]%n",&temp, &count);
    if(res != 1){
        break;
    }
    printf("%s\n", temp);
    printf("%d\n", count);
    str = str + count;

}

printf("%s", temp);

return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Any reason you want to do this using `sscanf`? Just loop through the letters and print them and add one to a counter if it is between `'a'` and `'z'` inclusively.

Comment: Yes, I was just taught this and I would like to become more familiar with its uses.

Comment: skip UPPERCASE letter when `if(res != 1){` , not break

Comment: these lines: str[2] = 'E';
str[3] = 'f';
str[4] = '\0'; should be setting offsets 4,5,6 not 2,3,4

Comment: this code block: if(str == NULL){
    printf("Error");
} needs to call exit(1) or return(1), because the char* str is not pointing to an allocated section of the heap memory when malloc returned NULL

Comment: this code block: if(res != 1){
        break;
    } should always break, because sscanf returns the number of parameters filled (2 in this case)

Comment: any scanf family function stops when a non matching character is reached. so the scan stops when it sees the 'C' character.

Comment: this format of main: main() is not valid, it must always contain a return value, almost always an int value.  Also the code is returning an int value.  So the compiler should have issued warnings.  Do you have all the warnings/errors messages enabled?

Comment: this line: printf("Error");  in general, error messages should be output to stderr.  the perror() function outputs to stderr.  suggest using perror( "malloc" );  Which will also print out the current message related to the errno variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main(){
    char *str = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    char temp[200];
    int count = 0;
    if(str == NULL){
        printf("Error");
    }

    str[0] = 'a';
    str[1] = 'b';
    str[2] = 'C';
    str[3] = 'd';
    str[4] = 'E';//index!!
    str[5] = 'f';
    str[6] = '\0';
    int res;
    char *p = str;//You do not change the str directly
    while(1){
        res = sscanf(p, "%[a-z]%n", temp, &count);
        if(res == EOF){
            break;
        } else if(res == 0){
            ++p;
            continue;
        }
        printf("%s\n", temp);
        printf("%d\n", count);
        p += count;

    }

    //printf("%s", temp);
    free(str);
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. I see what I was doing wrong.

Comment: At last bluepixy, someone saw my answer and edited, was about to comment! (and I saw your free(), +1) :) @Tornadoe1123 be more careful before accepting an answer. Inform the author of the answer, in order (s)he to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you had your array element tangled up:

```
  str[0] = 'a';
  str[1] = 'b';
  str[2] = 'C';
  str[3] = 'd';
  str[2] = 'E';
  str[3] = 'f';
  str[4] = '\0';
```

I changed it fro 0 to 6.

Second, check the warnings of your compiler. You should get these two:

```
warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [enabled by default]
warning: format ‘%[a-z’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char (*)[200]’ [-Wformat]
```

The problem is that you are passing `&temp`.

Then you should understand that `temp` will be overwritten at every loop, so you need another array which will collect the `temp` of every loop.

Then, when `res` is not one, this means that you found at least one uppercase letter, thus advance the `str` pointer and `continue`, don't `break`.

When to `break`? When the length of `str` is zero.

Putting all together, you get this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

  char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
  char temp[200];
  char result[200] = "\0";
  int count = 0;
  if (str == NULL) {
    printf("Error");
  }

  str[0] = 'a';
  str[1] = 'b';
  str[2] = 'C';
  str[3] = 'd';
  str[4] = 'E';
  str[5] = 'f';
  str[6] = '\0';
  int res;
  while (1) {
    if(!strlen(str))
      break;

    res = sscanf(str, "%[a-z]%n", temp, &count);

    if (res != 1) {
      str = str + 1;
      continue;
    }
    printf("temp = %s\n", temp);
    printf("count = %d\n", count);
    str = str + count;
    strcat(result, temp);
  }

  printf("%s", result);
  free(str);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
temp = ab
count = 2
temp = d
count = 1
temp = f
count = 1
abdf
```

Comment: this line: str = str + count; is not correct, as the above 'if' code block is already moved the pointer.  Also, you do not want to corrupt the pointer to the str array, rather use a separate char * and scanf, etc using the separate char *

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it that way : you ask `scanf` to get all lower case it can into temp. On first pass, it has `abEf` (*) and it gets `ab`. But on second pass, it has only "Ef" and it cannot read anything so it return 0.

Unsure you wanted that but you overwrite str[2-3] ...

IMHO, it would be easier to browse the initial string and copy into another string the lowercase characters ...

If you really want to use scanf, you must skip one character after each read (either successful or not) and stop when string is exhausted

Comment: Had to read your answer a couple of times before I could understand it. Yes thank you very much, I see what I was doing wrong.